# How to check whether the data is in a CSV file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i have data csv

```
word,label
relax,1
angry,0
happy,1
sad,3
```

and I want to check whether the word already exists in CSV data

My code is like this and doesn't match what I want

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data/hasil_cluster2.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1") 
ip="key"
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    if ip is row[0]:
        print('data found')
        break
    else:
        print(row[0])
```

Comment: you want to check if specific header exist?

Comment: or you want to check  some data in all the rows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It check complete dataframe the key if abc exist in any column it would return those rows else it would be empty

```
key = 'abc'
df = df[df.eq(key).any(axis=1)]
if df.empty:
    print("empty")
else:
   print("key found")
```

Comment: @MuhammadRusli great accept or upvote if you found it helpful